# Replacement for Normalizer.getClass(c) method in Java 6

Tags: java

The `getClass(char c)` method from Normalizer class seems to be missing from Java 6 onwards.

This method is present in our legacy code and is being used as shown below. We need to migrate it to Java 6. Any suggestions on how it can be replaced?

```
import sun.text.Normalizer;

 /**
 * Returns an array of strings that have all the possible
 * permutations of the characters in the input string.
 * This is used to get a list of all possible orderings
 * of a set of combining marks. Note that some of the permutations
 * are invalid because of combining class collisions, and these
 * possibilities must be removed because they are not canonically
 * equivalent.
 */
private String[] producePermutations(String input) {
    if (input.length() == 1)
        return new String[] {input};

    if (input.length() == 2) {
        if (getClass(input.charAt(1)) ==
            getClass(input.charAt(0))) {
            return new String[] {input};
        }
        String[] result = new String[2];
        result[0] = input;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2);
        sb.append(input.charAt(1));
        sb.append(input.charAt(0));
        result[1] = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }

    int length = 1;
    for(int x=1; x<input.length(); x++)
        length = length * (x+1);

    String[] temp = new String[length];

    int combClass[] = new int[input.length()];
    for(int x=0; x<input.length(); x++)
        combClass[x] = getClass(input.charAt(x));

    // For each char, take it out and add the permutations
    // of the remaining chars
    int index = 0;
loop:   for(int x=0; x<input.length(); x++) {
        boolean skip = false;
        for(int y=x-1; y>=0; y--) {
            if (combClass[y] == combClass[x]) {
                continue loop;
            }
        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(input);
        String otherChars = sb.delete(x, x+1).toString();
        String[] subResult = producePermutations(otherChars);

        String prefix = input.substring(x, x+1);
        for(int y=0; y<subResult.length; y++)
            temp[index++] =  prefix + subResult[y];
    }
    String[] result = new String[index];
    for (int x=0; x<index; x++)
        result[x] = temp[x];
    return result;
}

private int getClass(char c) {
    return Normalizer.getClass(c);
}
```

Comment: You wrote sun.text.Normailer, but linked the javadoc from java.text.Normalizer. Was this a mistake or did you answer your question by accident?

Comment: sorry, removed the reference now.

Comment: Classes from `sun` package get merged to `java` over time. `CharSequence` is another example.

Comment: What is that code intended to do?

Comment: @tbodt I have added the entire code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalizer from `java.text` has no same functionalities of `Normalizer` from `sun.text`

Based only on this piece of code you entered, the easy way to do what you want is use `ICU4J` dependency. If you use maven, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you can write a class like this:

```
package com.ibm.icu.text;

public class Normalizer {

    public static final int getClass(final char ch) {
        final int value = DecompData.canonClass.elementAt(ch);
        return value >= 0 ? value : value + 256;
    }

}
```

Since `DecompData` has package-private visibility, create `Normalizer` in same package in you application.

Comment: It's legacy code, so it might be hard to add a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet, as others have pointed out, is `sun.text.Normalizer` and not `java.text.Normalizer`. In Java 6 I see that `sun.text.Normalizer` has a method called `getCombiningClass(int ch)` which is described as "Returns the combining class of the given character" despite taking an `int` and not a `char`. This is probably the method you are looking for.

I should note that, being a `sun.*` class, these sorts of methods are subject to these sorts of changes (renaming, disappearing) with no notice, and you use them at your own risk. Caveat coder!

Answer (score 2):

In Java 6, the method was renamed to `getCharacterClass`, and the parameter was changed from a `char` to an `int`, because that sort of replacement was done everywhere to accommodate Unicode characters with values greater than 65,535.

A method from a package that started with `sun` should never have been used in the first place. That's probably why the call is in a separate method, in case it needs to be rewritten if the method is removed. Unfortunately, I can't find an equivalent in the public Java API, so the replacement will have to be either written from scratch or undocumented.